Show base64 encode data in new tab
I get  base64 encode  data from the server which I need to show a preview of that pdf file in new tab on click. File can be in pdf with size 6 MB. In the Url on open it is turncated.
<a href="data:image/png;base64,..." target="_blank">preview</a>

How Can I show the base64 encode  data in a new tab?
I found this Show base64 encoded data in new tab Rails which is not clear yet.
I am using reactjs and javascript
const signatures = {
    JVBERi0: "application/pdf",
    R0lGODdh: "image/gif",
    R0lGODlh: "image/gif",
    iVBORw0KGgo: "image/png",
    "/9j/": "image/jpg"
  };
  const detectMimeType= (b64) => {
    for (var s in signatures) {
      if (b64.indexOf(s) === 0) {
        return signatures[s];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
const showPreview = (e,base64_data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const mime_type = detectMimeType(base64_data);
    let data = "data:"+mime_type+";base64," + base64_data;
    var w = window.open("");
      w.document.write(data);
    
  }

I am not getting any error with showPreview it is printing the data uri to the page.

Can't you just use target="_blank" to open it in a new tab? As far as I know you are not allowed to programmatically open data: urls with something like window.open (for some security reason I have forgotten now), but you can link to them and let the browser open them.

@somethinghere a link with target="_blank" would still be considered "top level navigation", and that is primarily what gets blocked, see https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/ Although it says right below on that page, 'Opening “data:application/pdf” and “data:application/json"' was allowed.

Can you please clarify, what the actual problem is? Are you getting an error from the browser, saying this was not allowed? "In the Url on open it is turncated." - or is that supposed to be the actual issue? (But with a 6MB file, you should probably not run into relevant limits either, according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs#length_limitations Base64 encoding means 4/3 of the original size, but with that you should still be below those numbers.)

@CBroe Ah yes indeed. Another option is converting the data URI into a blob and opening that as an Object URL, just tested that and that does work?

Data URIs have a length limit in browsers (which I don’t recall) so what you can do to overcome this is to convert the Data URI to a blob-URL like this...
function DataUri2Blob(dataURI){

var B=atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]), L=B.length, A=[];

var Mime=dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

for(let i=0; i<L; i++){A.push(B.charCodeAt(i));}

return new Blob([new Uint8Array(A)],{type:Mime});}

Usage...
var dataURI='data:image/png;base64,.....';

let Blob=DataUri2Blob(dataURI);

let Url=URL.createObjectURL(Blob);

And then fire up the Url variable in a new window/tab.
And two seconds later...
URL.revokeObjectURL(Url);


You don't even need to wait two seconds, you can immediately revoke it and it should still work. As long as what you were handling has been done before you revoke, it should work. Als the URI limit is about 4Mb if I remember correctly.

Ahhh depends… I’ve seen situations in my image manipulating proggy where I really had to delay. Better safe than sorry.

Could be then, I only quickly tested this with a basically empty SVG. The problem is that two seconds doesn't really help then either depending on file size... Perhaps just clean up at some other interaction point altogether (like when the window regains focus or something).

Agree.. I always use a process terminating flag before revoking, but here it's just a demo.

I had to think but a quicker way to turn a data URI into a blob is to just do await fetch( dataURI ).then(r => r.blob())? No need to write the internal code yourself. Not sure if there are any drawbacks to this, but I can't think of any immediately?

Yeah… but going async has its drawbacks and new challenges; which I’d rather avoid if possible.

I'm going to disagree with how hard that is, but either way works.

This actually worked to me. I converted the uri to blob and blob opened in a new window
const showPreview = (e,base64_data) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const mime_type = detectMimeType(base64_data);
    let data = "data:"+mime_type+";base64," + base64_data;
    let blobData = dataURLtoBlob(data);
    var w = window.open('about:blank');
    w.location = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
      
  }
  const dataURLtoBlob=(dataurl) => {
    var arr = dataurl.split(','), mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1],
        bstr = atob(arr[1]), n = bstr.length, u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
    while(n--){
        u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
    }
    return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
  }


Same thing here: if you make showPreview async you could just use await fetch( base64_data ).then(r => r.blob()) to generate the blob instead of writing your own function for this.
